# Can't step into function during debugging session in Clion

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, clion

I am trying out CLion as new IDE and I have this odd problem with debugging. I am trying to step into function cropImage (not method) but all I can get when stepping into is to get to constructor of CRect.

```
int main ( void )
{
    cropImage( "./sample/input_00.raw", "./output_00.raw", CRect(1,2,3,4), ENDIAN_LITTLE);
    return 0;
}
```

Also, when I try to put breakpoint inside function `cropImage()` it just get ignored. What am I doing wrong? I think this is pretty much basic function of debugger to step into function, not only methods...

I am using CLion on Linux with GDB and g++.

EDIT:
Just to clarify the code and issue here is how the file main.cpp looks

```
bool cropImage ( const char  * srcFileName,
                 const char  * dstFileName,
                 const CRect & rc,
                 int           byteOrder )
{
    // Open streams, create objects, do stuff
}

int main ( void )
{
    cropImage( "./sample/input_00.raw", "./output_00.raw", CRect(1,2,3,4), ENDIAN_LITTLE);
    return 0;
}
```

Everything works from CLI ( using gdb on binary created from CLion ), it just that inside of IDE it ignores any breakpoint inside `cropImage()` function.

Comment: And what is `cropImage`? Is it your own function, with a definition in the CLion project? Does it come from an external library?

Comment: It is my own function, defined in the same file as `main(void)`

Comment: And what does it do? It haven't been optimized away because the compiler doesn't think it does anything? Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Comment: Just to check - did you build the debug configuration?

Comment: clion is a paid product. Don't they have a tech support team?

Comment: Yes, I am using debug configuration when building.
I can't really copy exact code here, because it is assignment but the general idea of this function is: 
open stream,
initialize objects,
do some stuff with them
return true / false

It works without issue when I use gdb from CLI so I think this should be just some wrong settings in my IDE. @RichardHodges I will try that to contact support, good idea.

Comment: Did you turn off compiler optimization?

Comment: @dbrank0 I didn't though should it really be an issue? When I run the code it executes the function I just want to use debugger to step into and analyze my code and find the place where it breaks.

Comment: If optimization is turned on, function may have been inlined, so you can't step into it anymore. And any debugging may be unpredictable, with anything more than -Og optimization level.

Answer (score 1):

So I find this workaround. Ref: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206606815-Integrated-GDB-and-a-frame-not-available-error

Seems like it's issue on ArchLinux. Even though CLion detects gdb automatically without problems, frames doesn't exist and manually specifying path to gdb (`/usr/bin/gdb`) fixed this.